# How to advance 3 images at one time in Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have made a carousel which contain three images as a group.

For example:
<[1][2][3]>

Currently when you hit right arrow, it only goes one image at a time.
<[2][3][4]>

I would like to know when clicking on the arrow, how to show/advance to the next three images.

Like this:
<[4][5][6]>

Here's some code:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
       <div class="col-md-4">image1</div>
     </div>

     <div class="item">
       <div class="col-md-4">image2</div>
     </div>

      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-md-4">image3</div>
     </div>

      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-md-4">image4</div>
     </div>

      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-md-4">image5</div>
     </div>

      <div class="item">
       <div class="col-md-4">image6</div>
     </div>

    </div></div>

     <script>

    $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
      var next = $(this).next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

      if (next.next().length>0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
      else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
      }
    });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at boostrap's specifications, there doesn't seem to be an option to modify this manually.You'd have to try to override it somehow, which is probably gonna be ugly and a lot of work.

I would suggest just using a library where this parameter is adjustable with only one variable. I've used [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) before, and it's very easy to use. If you look at the example "multiple-items" it looks like exactly what you're looking for.

```
$('.multiple-items').slick({
     infinite: true,
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting slick to me. It is very useful!

Comment: Not a problem, and yes it's pretty awesome!